# POST request (python) - invalid request

Tags: python, api, session, post, python-requests

I'm trying to use the API of a media ID registry, the EIDR, to download tv show information. I'd like to be able to query many shows automatically. I'm not experienced in how to use APIs, and the [documentation](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/eidr) for this specific one is very opaque. I'm using python 3 (requests library) in Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried sending a request for a specific tv show. I took the headers and parameters information from the browser, as in, I did the query from the browser (I looked up 'anderson cooper 360' [from this page](https://ui.eidr.org/search)) and then looked at the information in the "network" tab of the browser's page inspector. I used the following code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://resolve.eidr.org/EIDR/query/'

headers = {'Host': 'ui.eidr.org', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) \ 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0', \ 
'Accept': '*/*', \ 
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', \ 
'Referer': 'https://ui.eidr.org/search/results/19c70c63d73790b86f3fb385f2a9b3f4', \ 
'Cookie': 'ci_session=f4tnbi8qm7oaq30agjtn8p69j91s4li4; \ 
_ga=GA1.2.1738620664.1519337357; _gid=GA1.2.1368695940.1519337357; _gat=1', \ 
'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

params = {'search_page_size':25, 'CustomAsciiSearch[_v]':1, \ 
'search_type':'content', 'ResourceName[_v]':'anderson cooper 360', \ 
'AlternateResourceNameAddition[_v]':1, \ 
'AssociatedOrgAlternateNameAddition[_v]':1, 'Status[_v]':'valid'}

r = requests.post(url, data=params, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

I get this response that basically says it's an invalid request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response \ 
xmlns="http://www.eidr.org/schema" version="2.1.0"><Status>\ 
<Code>3</Code><Type>invalid request</Type></Status></Response>
```

Now, I read in an answer to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37532409/7075263) that I should somehow use a session object. The code suggested in the answer by 
Padraic Cunningham was this:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:46.0) \ 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0','X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', \ 
"referer": "https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get("https://www.hackerearth.com")
    headers["X-CSRFToken"] = s.cookies["csrftoken"]
    r = s.post("https://www.hackerearth.com/AJAX/filter-challenges/?modern=true", \
    headers=headers, files={'submit': (None, 'True')})
    print(r.json())
```

So I understand that I should somehow use this, but I don't fully understand why or how.

So my question(s) would be:

1) What does 'invalid request' mean in this case?

2) Do you have any suggestions for how to write the request in a way that I can iterate it many times for different items I want to look up?

3) Do you know what I should do to properly use a session object here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you probably need [this documentation](http://eidr.org/documents/EIDR_2.0_REST_API.pdf).

1) from the documentation:

**invalid request**: An API (URI) that does not exist including missing a required
parameter. May also include an incorrect HTTP operation on a valid
URI (such as a GET on a registration). Could also be POST multipart
data that is syntactically invalid such as missing required headers or
if the end-of-line characters are not CR-LF.

2) As far as I understand, this API accepts XML requests. See what appears after clicking on 'View XML' on the web page with results (https://ui.eidr.org/search/results). For the 'anderson cooper 360' you can use the XML data in Python like this:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://resolve.eidr.org/EIDR/query/'

headers =  {'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    'Authorization': 'Eidr 10.5238/webui:10.5237/D4C9-7E59:9kDMO4+lpsZGUIl8doWMdw==',
    'EIDR-Version': '2.1'}
xml_query = """<Request xmlns="http://www.eidr.org/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Operation>
            <Query>
                    <Expression><![CDATA[ASCII(((/FullMetadata/BaseObjectData/ResourceName "anderson" AND /FullMetadata/BaseObjectData/ResourceName "cooper" AND /FullMetadata/BaseObjectData/ResourceName "360") OR (/FullMetadata/BaseObjectData/AlternateResourceName "anderson" AND /FullMetadata/BaseObjectData/AlternateResourceName "cooper" AND /FullMetadata/BaseObjectData/AlternateResourceName "360")) AND /FullMetadata/BaseObjectData/Status "valid")]]></Expression>
                    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                    <PageSize>25</PageSize>
            </Query>
    </Operation>
</Request>"""
r = requests.post(url, data=xml_query, headers=headers)
root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
for sm in root.findall('.//{http://www.eidr.org/schema}SimpleMetadata'):
    print({ch.tag.replace('{http://www.eidr.org/schema}',''):ch.text for ch in sm.getchildren()})
```

3) I don't think you need the session object.